# Multifunctional buttons within jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
             var visible = $(".sidebarcontent1").is(":visible");
             $(".sidebarcontent1").show(); visible ? "hide" : "show";
             $(".sidebarcontent").show();
             $(".sidebarcontent2").hide();
             $(".sidebarcontent3").hide();
             $(".sidebarcontent4").hide();
         });
```

I want to have it so I click the button when it's shown, it will go to hide. vice versa but this doesn't work.

Comment: @OP : Can you please be more specific as to what you want?

Comment: I want the first click make the sidebarcontent1 show, and if I click the same button again it must hide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $(".sidebarcontent1").toggle();
    $(".sidebarcontent").show();
    $(".sidebarcontent2").hide();
    $(".sidebarcontent3").hide();
    $(".sidebarcontent4").hide();
});
```

Comment: I've found the answer thanks youe ! using the toggle function works! cheers

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    var visible = $(".sidebarcontent1").is(":visible");
    $(".sidebarcontent1, .sidebarcontent").toggle(visible);
    $(".sidebarcontent2, .sidebarcontent3, .sidebarcontent4").toggle(!visible);
});
```

Comment: Now provide a jsFiddle if you want more help. I don't know which menus you are talking about...